# Problemas con doWhile

Tags: c, while

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char L[20];
  int num, aux, largo, mitad, i, C[20], firstD, n = 0;
  bool sino;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  do { /*Solicitar el numero*/
    printf("Escribe un numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*Convierte el int a String para leer el largo de la cifra*/
    sprintf(L, "%d", num);
    /*Lee el número de dígitos de la cifra*/
    largo = strlen(L);
    /*Mitad*/
    mitad = largo / 2;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*Separa el número en cifras para conocer la primera cifra*/
    aux = num;
    while (aux > 0) {
      C[n] = aux % 10;
      aux = aux / 10;
      n++;
    }
    firstD = C[largo - 1];
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*Comprueba si­ es pali­ndromo*/
    for (i = 0; i <= mitad; i++) {
      if (firstD != C[0]) {
        sino = 0;
      } else {
        sino = 1;
      }
    }
    if (sino == 1) {
      printf("Si es palindromo");
    } else {
      printf("No es palindromo");
    }
  } while (num != 0);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  printf("\n");
}
```

Tengo problemas con este código, resulta que tengo que pedirle al usuario un
numero y calcular si es palindromo un determinado número de veces, el programa
se detiene cuando el usuario ingresa un 0. El problema es que al principio todo
bien, pero por ejemplo, si ingreso un 22 y después un 35 la variable **sino**
parece quedarse ciclada y no importa que número ingrese, si el primero fue
palindromo todos los demás números que sigan los leera como palindromo (esto
funciona con numeros mayores a 10) y no sé como solucionarlooo, ¿Alguien podría
ayudarme?

Comment: Porque ejecuta un bucle para determinar si es palindromo y no usas el indice para hacerlo: `/*Comprueba si­ es pali­ndromo*/
    for(i=0;i<=mitad;i++){
        if(firstD!=C[0]){sino=0;
        }else{sino=1;}
}`, en cada iteracion te traerá el mismo resultado porque siempre ingresa al primer elemento de tu array.

Comment: Si solo necesitas el ultimo numero, puedes usar la variable `L` que contiene la cadena, ya sea usando la funcion `atoit(cadena); ` o convirtiendo el chat directamente a entero: `firstD=L[largo-1]-'0';/*Recuerda C ve a los chat como si fueran un entero, por lo que podemos aprovecharlo.*/`, te saldría mucho mas util que iterar sobre `aux` hasta llegar al ultimo digito

Comment: Dato interesante: En la verción std=c11 de c (Por lo comentario digo que es la que estas usando) te permite declarar variables dentro del bucle for: `for ( int i=0; i<=mitad; i++);` o `for ( int i=0; aux>0; i++ );`.

Comment: @DanielBriceño desde C99 se pueden declarar variables dentro de los bucles

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema es que solo te estás quedando con el resultado de la última cifra. Fíjate que el valor de `sino` lo machacas en cada iteración, sin importar qué valor tuviese anteriormente:

```
for (i = 0; i <= mitad; i++) {
  if (firstD != C[0]) {
    sino = 0;
  } else {
    sino = 1;
  }
}
```

En este caso, el algoritmo debería partir de la base de que el número es palíndromo y solo en el caso de encontrar una cifra que no cumpla, marcar `sino` a 0 y abortar el bucle, ya que en ese momento nada de lo que se haga podrá cambiar el resultado:

```
int sino = 1;
for (i = 0; i <= mitad; i++) {
  if (firstD != C[0]) {
    sino = 0;
    break;
  }
}
```

En cualquier caso, fíjate que estás haciendo trabajo por duplicado:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*Convierte el int a String para leer el largo de la cifra*/
    sprintf(L, "%d", num);
    /*Lee el número de dígitos de la cifra*/
    largo = strlen(L);
    /*Mitad*/
    mitad = largo / 2;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*Separa el número en cifras para conocer la primera cifra*/
    aux = num;
    while (aux > 0) {
      C[n] = aux % 10;
      aux = aux / 10;
      n++;
    }
    firstD = C[largo - 1];
```

Estas dos fases rellenan sendos arrays de caracteres, `L` y `C` **con el mismo contenido**. La única diferencia entre ambos será el finalizador de cadena de `L`, que no está presente en `C`. El código te quedaría más legible si eliminases uno de los dos arrays.

Como sugerencia, hay una forma más sencilla de comprobar si un número es palíndromo: creas un número con sus dígitos invertidos y comparas ambos números:

```
int numero = 12321;
int inverso = 0;
for( int temp=numero; temp != 0; temp /= 10 )
{
    inverso *= 10;
    inverso += temp % 10;
}

if (numero == inverso)
    puts("Palindromo\n");
else
    puts("No palindromo\n");
```

Comment: Todabia no entiendo porque se dejaria el bucle: `for ( int i=0; i<=mitad; i++ );`, creo que quedaria igual si se omitiera el bucle y solo se dejará el `if`.

Comment: Nota: Nunca se usa el indice en el `if` para el array `c`: `if ( firstD!=c[0] );`.

Comment: @DanielBriceño si no usas un bucle no puedes comprobar todos los caracteres de la secuencia. En C, el operador ==, al comparar arrays, lo que hace es comprobar la dirección de memoria del array, no su contenido

Comment: @DanielBriceño si no te refieres a eso, lo siento pero no he entendido tu comentario

Comment: nota que solo accede al primer elemento durante todo el bucle: `c[0]`: `sino=( firstD==c[0] )?1:0;`

Comment: @DanielBriceño Ah ya, bueno, había bastantes cosas que mejorar en ese código. A veces no tengo energías para enumerarlas todas. Si eso te chirría siempre escribe una nueva respuesta y así enriqueces el sitio

Comment: No, solo vi un descuido que quise que vieras para mejorar la respuesta. Tampoco se que es un polibalente y no tengo mucho interes en buscarlo, por eso no respondo la pregunta. Me disculpo si mis comentarios le disgustó un poco.